# How to target an specific columns after a delete without buttons

Tags: excel, vba

So i'm trying to make a code that deletes cells as long as they belong to the same column(horizontally) after deleting a cell from column "O".
Column N is all tick boxes linked to column FF. if they are set to true when the deletion happens, it should turn false.
Column O is where the deletion should happen( the objective is to simply press the cell and click delete or back space on the keyboard, not a button.)
Column P is sign date, which should also be deleted.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Update 20140722
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("O:O"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

haven't been able to set the boxes to false. also i can't choose multiple cells, it only deletes one at a time.

Comment: You are disabling events, this could be the reason the box doesnt update to False/True. Try to make it work without disabling events. Also to make it work when changing more than one, do not set WorkRng to anything, only compare if Target is inside the WorkRange, then loop all ranges inside Target.Range.

Comment: Where in your code do you refer to these tick boxes?

Comment: i was able to fix it by adding another line

~~~
Rng.Offset(, 147).Value = False
~~~

however now the other issue still remains, which is not all selected cells are applied to the code at the same time. it only does it one at a time

Comment: Change `For Each Rng In WorkRng` to `For Each Rng In Target.Range` and try it.

Answer (score -1):

This is the final result in which everything started working correctly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) '<----- Start of worksheet script
Dim WorkRng As Range '<----- selection
Dim Rng As Range '<----- selected cell(s)
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer '<----- idk lol
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("O:O"), Target) '<----- block selection for anything other than column O
xOffsetColumn = 1 '<----- Useless , but it means the cell one range forward will be changed.
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then '<----- if statement
    Application.EnableEvents = False '<----- idk what this is for but ok.
    For Each Rng In WorkRng '<----- Start of cell loop
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then '<----- Second start of if statement
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now '<----- Date and time
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy" '<----- Date and time format
        Else '<----- if's else statement.
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents '<----- Command for deletion.
            Rng.Offset(, 147).Value = False '<----- Tick Box sets to false.
        End If '<----- Second end of if statement
    Next Rng '<----- end of loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True '<----- I also don't know what this is for but ok.
End If '<----- First end of if statement.






End Sub
```